# Toggle a customized button in the New Mail Message Ribbon within Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, button, outlook, toggle, ribbon

I have created a new customized button that sets the Sensitivity to Confidential.

I would like the button to be able to do the following:

1. Toggle the setting each time the button is pressed (sets and unsets the confidential tag).
2. Be highlighted when the sensitivity setting is currently set to Confidential (similiar behavior to setting the 'high importance' tag.

.

```
Sub setConfidential()

ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: Toggle the setting each time the button is pressed (sets and unsets the confidential tag).

```
Sub ToggleSensitivity()
    if ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential then
        ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olNormal
    else
        ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential
    end if
End Sub
```